# MVC4 - Unobtrusive validation starting too early

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

I have a HTML form that uses unobtrusive validation in my website which is an ASP.Net MVC4 application. The form from my view is simple and is shown below

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @: Listing for @ViewBag.itemNumber
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Location)
  @:<input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

My controller is as shown below

```
public ActionResult test()
{
  string itemNumber = Request.params["item"];
  ViewBag.itemNumber = itemNumber;
  return View();
}
```

and my model is

```
public class item
{
 [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The Name should be atleast 3 characters in length", MinimumLength = 3)]
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string Location {get;set;}
}
```

The problem I am having is that the unobtrusive validation kicks in as soon as the page loads even before my first form submit. The textbox for Name turns red as soon as I start typing because of the minimum length validation.  I have used unobtrusive validation successfully and without this issue on other pages of the same website. I suspect that the validation is kicking in early on this particular page because of the code in my controller which retrieves a value from the URL GET parameters and sets it in the Viewbag. Is my assumption correct? If it is, how can I prevent the validation from starting too early on this page?

EDIT: I have the following javascript libraries on my page in the same order as specified below

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Your code has a few errors like `@:<input type="submit" value="Save />` is missing a ", and `public class item()` won't even compile. It is probably not your problem since you cannot expect any behaviour if it won't run :). I have noticed that ASP.NET MVC4 will validate when say a text input loses focus. Can't remember any validation happened before the first submit in ASP.NET MVC 3, but perhaps you have some javascript that plays with the focus?

Comment: @Silvermind - I have fixed the typos :). I had to change the names of my real class and the real fields to make it generic enough to post here. Thats why it had errors that would have prevented it from compiling.

Comment: @user1 so how have you solved this issue of **validation starting too early**? I got [the similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775863/why-i-see-validation-messages-before-form-submiting)

Comment: @efr - See the accepted answer below. the validation starting too early is the default behavior because fields are validated onkeyup. I did not do anything to solve the problem. I just accepted it as expected behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one you described is the default behaviour! Fields are validated also onKeyUp as default. This doesn happens with required fields simply because when the key is up the textbox is not empty anymore! So maybe you are confused with the behaviour of the required field case.
Anyway you can disable the keyUp validation. See here the full options of the plugin you can change : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Comment: Validation (including keyup validation) usually kicks in only after the form submit has been attempted atleast one time. My page is starting the keyup validation even before attempting a single submit.

Comment: I might have spoken too soon. Turns out the simplest answer is sometimes the right one! I was confused with the behavior of the required field case! Thanks for clearing that up for me. I cannot award the bounty for another 12 hours but will do it to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your rendered HTML page (i.e. View Source)?

I'm interested in looking at which .js packs you are using.

Maybe you are using an old/buggy `jquery-1....js` pack. I just tested your example code using the jquery-1.6.2.js version (FYI: the latest version is 1.8.2) and the unobtrusive js worked as expected.

The symptom of your problem certainly sounds like a client side issue (JavaScript), so being able to see your rendered web page may help us help you.

By the way; you code examples still have typos. Your `View` code should look something like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @ViewBag.itemNumber
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Location)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

**UPDATE**
I created an MVC 4 app based on what you posted. Here is the rendered HTML.

*Notice the JavaScript packs I included. It's very possible that your problem is due to a missing js pack.*

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>test</title>
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <h2>test</h2>
    <form action="/" method="post">
<input data-val="true" data-val-length="The Name should be at least 3 characters in length" data-val-length-max="10" data-val-length-min="3" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
<input id="Location" name="Location" type="text" value="" />  
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I am using jquery 1.8.2. There is no other custom javascript on that page

Comment: If you want to use unobtrusive js, then you'll need to include that js pack. Take a look at the update to my answer for more details.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I do not have any custom javascript code on that page but I have edited my question to show the libraries that are used

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Turns out, it was just me not understanding unobtrusive validation correctly (see Fransesco's answer).