# why I see validation messages before form submiting

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I've created a form and when I load the page with it I see validation messages before I submit the form. Why? You can [download my code from github](https://github.com/ypapax/MyMustAgreeValidation)

[The similar question. It's because of mvc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033721/mvc4-unobtrusive-validation-starting-too-early)

```
@model MyMustAgreeValidation.Models.NewUserProfileModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        @Html.MyEditFor(m=>m.Login)
        @Html.MyEditFor(m=>m.Password)
        @Html.MyEditFor(m=>m.ConfirmPassword)
        @Html.MyEditFor(m=>m.DisplayName)
        @Html.MyEditFor(m=>m.Email)
        @Html.MyEditFor(m=>m.Homepage)
        @Html.MyEditFor(m=>m.AgreementAccepted)
        <p><input type="submit" value="@CreateRes.CreateProfileButton"/></p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Where `Html.MyEditFor` is

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyEditFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return html.Partial("Item", new LabelEditorValidation() { Label = html.LabelFor(expression), Editor = html.EditorFor(expression), Validation = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression) });
    }
```

And `Item` is partial view:

```
@model MyMustAgreeValidation.Models.LabelEditorValidation
<div class="editor-label">
    @Model.Label
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Model.Editor
    @Model.Validation
</div>
```

LabelEditorValidation:

```
public class LabelEditorValidation
{
    public MvcHtmlString Label { get; set; }
    public MvcHtmlString Editor { get; set; }
    public MvcHtmlString Validation { get; set; }
}
```

Scripts included:

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>        
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/Validation/EqualAttribute.js"></script>
```

Form model NewUserProfileModel:

```
 public class NewUserProfileModel : UserProfileModel, IValidatableObject
{
    [Display(Name="Password", ResourceType = typeof(NewUserProfileRes))]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes))]
    [StringLengthRange(6, 64, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidStringLength")]
    public string Password { get; set; }


    [Display(Name="ConfirmPassword", ResourceType = typeof(NewUserProfileRes))]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(NewUserProfileRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordsDontMatch")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="AgreementAccepted", ResourceType = typeof(NewUserProfileRes))]
    [Equal(true, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(NewUserProfileRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustAgreeWithEULA")]
    public bool AgreementAccepted { get; set; }

    public NewUserProfileModel()
    {
        var property = GetType().GetProperty("Login");
        var list = property.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var userRepository = new UserRepository();
        if (userRepository.IsLoginExists(Login))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(NewUserProfileRes.LoginAlreadyExists, new []{"Login"});
        }
    }
```

UserProfileModel:

```
 public class UserProfileModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Login", ResourceType = typeof(UserProfileRes))]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes))]
    [StringLengthRange(3, 64, ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidStringLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes))]
    public string Login { get; set; }


    [Display(Name="DisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(UserProfileRes))]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldIsRequired",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes))]
    [StringLengthRange(3, 32, 
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidStringLength",
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes))]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(UserProfileRes))]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldIsRequired")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidEmailAddress")]
    [StringLength(64, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringTooLong")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Homepage", ResourceType = typeof(UserProfileRes))]
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    [RegularExpression(@"(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IvalidUrl")]
    [StringLength(96,
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorsRes), ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringTooLong")]
    public string Homepage { get; set; }
}
```

EqualAttribute.js:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("equal", function (value, element, param) {
    if($(element).attr("type")=="checkbox")
    {
        value = String($(element).attr("checked"));
        param = param.toLowerCase();
    }
    return (value == param);
});

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("equal", "valuetocompare");
```

Comment: Have you included the proper validation .js files on the page?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Another "throw it at the wall" and see what happens idea: is there any custom javascript messing with the inputs that could be automatically triggering the validation?

Comment: Really nice code.  Does your problem exist if you don't use your custom helper?  Should be an easy test.

Comment: @TreyGramann tryed without helper: `@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Password)
            @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Password)`. The same result

Comment: @da7rutrak Tryed to disable custom unotrusive validation deleting `<script src="~/Scripts/Validation/EqualAttribute.js"></script>`. The same result

Comment: How do you set your `jquery.validate.js` plugin options?  Set these options, `onkeyup: false` and `onfoucout: false` which leaves `submit` as the only event to trigger a validation test.

Comment: @Sparky ok, I set: `<script>
        $($("form").validate({
            onkeyup: false,
            onclick: false
        }));
    </script>`. The same result.

Comment: If `.validate()` has already been called someplace else to initialize the plugin, simply calling `$("form").validate({ onkeyup: false, onclick: false })` will do nothing.  The plugin's options cannot be changed dynamically unless there's a method for it.  I know a lot about the jQuery Validation plugin, however, I wish I knew more about how it works within your framework along with the Unobtrusive Validation script.  Good luck.

Comment: @Sparky I have no client javascript except `jQuery.validator.addMethod("equal", function (value, element, param) {
    if($(element).attr("type")=="checkbox")
    {
        value = String($(element).attr("checked"));
        param = param.toLowerCase();
    }
    return (value == param);
});

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("equal", "valuetocompare");` I tried to disable it - the same result. The rest script generated automatically due to data anotations of form model.

Comment: That's my point... I really do not know if `.validate()` is being initialized from someplace else, because I am not familiar enough with your framework.  If it is being initialized someplace else, that is the place where you'd need to remove it, control it, disable it, edit it, or whatever.